# How to resolve internal variables with python yaml?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a file `test.yml` :

```
---
Servers:
  Server1:
    location: "Earth"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.0", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:00"}
    inbound: "{{ Configs.Earth.allowed_connections }}"

  Server2:
    location: "Earth"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.1", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:02"}
    inbound: "{{ Configs.Earth.allowed_connections }}"

  Server3:
    location: "Moon"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.2", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:02"}

  Server4:
    location: "Mars"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.3", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:03"}
    inbound: "{{ Configs.Mars.allowed_connections }}"

Configs:
  Earth:
    allowed_connections:
      - 99.99.99.99
      - 99.99.99.98
      - 99.99.99.97

  Mars:
    allowed_connections:
      - 88.99.99.99
      - 88.99.99.98
      - 88.99.99.97
```

I'd like to resolve the `inbound` variables when I load the yml file with python. Is there a way to do this natively? Or will I need to write a function that searches for any variables containing `"{{ }}"` and then reset them.

The solution needs to allow for varying depths that the variables could be located at.

I have no issues loading the file with `yaml.load` it's the variable resolution I'm struggling with

Comment: Neither `ruamel.yaml` nor the outdated PyYAML and PySyck support this kind of expansion. You'll need to do the expansion in a templating package that recognises the syntax (such as jinja2) and then reload the expanded document. Please note that the [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Jinja template module here please see below example:

```
import yaml
from jinja2 import Environment

jsonobj = yaml.full_load(your_yaml_stream)
print jsonobj
print Environment().from_string(your_yaml_stream).render(jsonobj)
```

Output generated will be:

```
Servers:
  Server1:
    location: "Earth"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.0", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:00"}
    inbound: "['99.99.99.99', '99.99.99.98', '99.99.99.97']"

  Server2:
    location: "Earth"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.1", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:02"}
    inbound: "['99.99.99.99', '99.99.99.98', '99.99.99.97']"

  Server3:
    location: "Moon"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.2", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:02"}

  Server4:
    location: "Mars"
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.3", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:03"}
    inbound: "['88.99.99.99', '88.99.99.98', '88.99.99.97']"

Configs:
  Earth:
    allowed_connections:
      - 99.99.99.99
      - 99.99.99.98
      - 99.99.99.97

  Mars:
    allowed_connections:
      - 88.99.99.99
      - 88.99.99.98
      - 88.99.99.97
```

Comment: sorry, should've mentioned that I know how to read in the file. It's the variable resolution that I'm struggling with.

Comment: You've answered the question so I've marked it accepted. Quick addition - is there a way to have those `inbound` variable as a proper yaml list instead of a string?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` will be able to fix it

Comment: Is there a special reason to use PyYAML in your solution? It only supports YAML 1.1, which was outdated ten years ago. It happens that it doesn't matter for the OPs example, but you should at least mention the restrictions in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use anchors/aliases for this.

Eg for a reduced version of your example

```
>>> import yaml
>>> doc = """
Configs: 
  Mars: 
    allowed_connections: &mars # Mark this as an anchor
      - 88.99.99.99 
      - 88.99.99.98 
      - 88.99.99.97 
Servers: 
  Server: 
    location: "Mars" 
    network: {ip: "0.0.0.3", mac: "00:00:00:00:00:03"} 
    inbound: *mars  # references the anchor here
"""
>>> from pprint import pprint # just for formatting
>>> pprint(yaml.load(doc))
{'Configs': {'Mars': {'allowed_connections': ['88.99.99.99',
                                              '88.99.99.98',
                                              '88.99.99.97']}},
 'Servers': {'Server': {'inbound': ['88.99.99.99',
                                    '88.99.99.98',
                                    '88.99.99.97'],
                        'location': 'Mars',
                        'network': {'ip': '0.0.0.3',
                                    'mac': '00:00:00:00:00:03'}}}}
```

Note that the config section has to be before the server section so that it can be referenced.

More examples [here](https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for your function:
`("(.*?)")`
It will find all words under quotes. You will just have to check if there is "Configs.Mars.allowed_connections" in the string.

[Check this exemple of regex](https://regex101.com/r/NpFfeY/1)