# Resolving internal variables in YAML file

Tags: python, variables, yaml, resolve

I have a YAML file which uses keys as references/variables in different sections as in the following example.

```
download:
  input_data_dir: ./data/input

prepare:
  input_dir: ${download.input_data_dir}
  output_dir: ./data/prepared

process:
  version: 1
  output_dir: ./output/${process.version}
```

I tried loading the YAML file in Python `params = yaml.safe_load(open("../params.yaml"))`. This outputs  `${download.input_data_dir}` for `params['prepare']['input_dir']`, while the expected output is `./data/input`. Similarly the expected output for `params['process']['output_dir']` is `./output/1`.

I wonder how the variables get resolved while loading the YAML file in Python to produce the expected results.

Comment: If you need "./data/input" as value, you have to read `params['download']['input_data_dir']`. That is what you have in your above YAML.

Comment: Thanks, Kabilesh for your quick reply. But the question is not about getting the value you need but using variables and resolving them when loading the YAML file so that you will get the expected results. In this case`./output/1` when you read `params['process']['output_dir]`.

Comment: Your expectation is completely unfounded as you don't have a YAML file which uses parameters, because YAML doesn't have parameters, or variables for that matter. YAML has anchors and aliases, and those can replace complete nodes but they use `&` resp. `*`, and you have none of those. That `${...}` construct you are referring to is nothing special for YAML it is just a string after loading. Any interpretation you will have to do in your program by walking over the data structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve internal variables with python yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733024/how-to-resolve-internal-variables-with-python-yaml)

Comment: Thanks, Tsyvarev for the link. It could be a simpler solution if it works. When I tried with the same yaml file from the link, I got  "TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes" form `Environment().from_string(your_yaml_stream)`!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define a custom constructor that processes such references, then add an implicit resolver that recognizes the pattern based on a RegEx so that your constructor will be called:

```py
import yaml, sys, re

class RefLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    # we override this method to remember the root node,
    # so that we can later resolve paths relative to it
    def get_single_node(self):
        self.cur_root = super(RefLoader, self).get_single_node()
        return self.cur_root

def ref_constructor(loader, node):
    cur = loader.cur_root
    # [2:-1] gets the path inside ${...}
    for item in node.value[2:-1].split("."):
        # cur.value, if it's a mappping, contains a list
        # of (key, value) tuples
        for (key, value) in cur.value:
            # key, if it's a scalar, contains its textual
            # content in key.value
            if key.value == item:
                cur = value
                break
    # defer construction to the default constructor of
    # the referred node
    return loader.construct_object(cur)

# register a custom tag for which our constructor is called
RefLoader.add_constructor("!ref", ref_constructor)

# tell PyYAML that a scalar that looks like `${...}` is to be
# implicitly tagged with `!ref`, so that our custom constructor
# is called.
RefLoader.add_implicit_resolver("!ref", re.compile(r'^\$\{[^}]*\}$'), None)

input = """
download:
  input_data_dir: ./data/input

prepare:
  input_dir: ${download.input_data_dir}
  output_dir: ./data/prepared

process:
  version: 1
  output_dir: ./output/${process.version}
"""

data = yaml.load(input, Loader=RefLoader)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

This yields:

```yaml
download:
  input_data_dir: ./data/input
prepare:
  input_dir: ./data/input
  output_dir: ./data/prepared
process:
  output_dir: ./output/${process.version}
  version: 1
```

As you can see, this currently only processes nodes that contain a scalar starting with `${` and ending with `}`; the value of `output_dir` isn't processed. This code serves as example on how to generally process references, you should be able to modify it to fit your specific needs.

Comment: This works for me and I have accepted your answer. Thanks, flyx!

Answer (score -1):

I have modified flyx's answer to get the results I wanted. I am posting my solution in case it is useful for others. It resolves any reference to the keys (used as variables) in an yaml file.

```
import yaml, sys, re

class RefLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    # we override this method to remember the root node,
    def get_single_node(self):
        self.cur_root = super(RefLoader, self).get_single_node()
        return self.cur_root

def ref_constructor(loader, node):
    result = ''
    start = 0
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, node.value):
        end, newstart = match.span()
        result += node.value[start:end]
        matched = match.group(1)

        cur = loader.cur_root # start from the root node
        for item in matched.split("."):
            # cur.value, if it's a mappping, contains a list
            # of (key, value) tuples
            for (key, value) in cur.value:
                # key, if it's a scalar, contains its textual
                # content in key.value
                if key.value == item:
                    cur = value
                    break
        result += cur.value
        start = newstart

    result += node.value[start:]
    return result

# register a custom tag for which our constructor is called
RefLoader.add_constructor("!ref", ref_constructor)

variable_pattern = r'\$\{([^}^{]+)\}'
pattern = re.compile(variable_pattern)

# tell PyYAML that a scalar that looks like `${...}` is to be implicitly tagged with `!ref`,
# so that our custom constructor is called.
RefLoader.add_implicit_resolver("!ref", re.compile(r'.*'+ variable_pattern + '.*'), None)


input = """
download:
  input_data_dir: ./data/input

prepare:
  input_dir: ${download.input_data_dir}
  output_dir: ./data/prepared

process:
  version: 1
  output_dir: ./output/${process.version}
"""

data = yaml.load(input, Loader=RefLoader)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

This now yields as I wanted:

```
download:
  input_data_dir: ./data/input
prepare:
  input_dir: ./data/input
  output_dir: ./data/prepared
process:
  output_dir: ./output/1
  version: 1
```